# Default active jQuery Tab

Tags: jquery

I am using the following markup for tabs and I would like to make tab-0 to be the default active tab on page load. How do I go about it?

```
 <div class="gdl-tab">
  <ul class="gdl-tab-title">
   <li><a data-tab="tab-0">ITEM_TITLE1 </a></li>
   <li><a data-tab="tab-1">ITEM_TITLE1</a></li>
  </ul>
 <div class="clear"></div>

 <ul class="gdl-tab-content"><li data-tab="tab-0">ADD_CONTENT_HERE</li><li data-tab="tab-1">ADD_CONTENT_HERE</li><li data-tab="tab-2">ADD_CONTENT_HERE</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Is it your custom tab then set selected tab in document.ready of jquery.

Comment: Provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), with external resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) then the first tab in the markup is already opened on default.

You can also set the active tab programatically if you wan't to be completely sure that the first tab is opened.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // setter
    $(".selector").tabs("option", "active", 0); //note that the number of tabs is zero based.
});
```